# Pass data from a Fragment to another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is my `Fragment_vent`. How can I pass data from `Fragment_vent` to another `Fragment`? `(putExtra("ext",IDV_L))`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    IDV_L = date();

    Fragment fragment = null;
    fragment = new Fragment_Inicio_Tab();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
}
```

Comment: This is easy if you just google it. Use setArguments() and getArguments() methods with your Fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code...

```
Fragment fragment = null;
fragment = new Fragment_Inicio_Tab();
Bundle args = new Bundle()
args.putString("value1", value1);
args.putString("value2", value2);
fragment.setArguments(args);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

and get in fragment as..

```
 getArguments().getString("value1");    
 getArguments().getString("value2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("message", "From Activity");
  //set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj=new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```